# Hardware maintenance scheduled for AWS RDS - What could be the down time for the RDS instance which is in single availability zone?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

One of my production RDS instance is scheduled for hardware maintenance. This instance is hosted in the single availability zone and storing the huge data. Now I'm worried that I cannot postpone the maintenance. Is there anyway I can reduce the downtime?

What happens during the hardware upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway I can reduce the downtime?

Pay [for redundancy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.MultiAZ.html).

> What happens during the hardware upgrade?

Nobody knows. Well, obviously Amazon does - but they don't tell you the details. It may be networking or server upgrades. Or UPS changes. Or whatever. That's part of the cloud; you buy a service, not a particular piece of hardware.